# Slicing articles from a photo or pdf newspaper page

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation

I have a pdf file which is a pdf format of a newspaper page that has many articles(image + text), same as the articles we find in the newspaper that newspaper vendor drops at our place everyday.

I wanted to ask if its possible to slice those articles from that pdf file somehow, pro-grammatically by using a library or using a tool?

If not pdf then is it possible slice those articles from that image file?

Comment: Welcome to photo.stackexchange. I've answered but I think this will be closed as off-topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about manipulating a PDF file, not about photography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

Ok, now how? Man, that's rough. At a former job I helped maintain and expand our PDF parser. PDF is a computer language for specifying page layout and content. So all the data you need is in there but it would be a big task to automate it.

Then again, if you only need to do this to a small number of PDFs you could *hope* that the text is actually text, not image data, and see if copy/paste work.

(Now, with that said, I do hope that you have permission of the copyright holder to do this if you intend to re-distribute the articles.)

Comment: OCR software - [Optical Character Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) is done on images containing text. Result is a text file.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for reply, I mentioned photo or pdf as the source given to me could be in either format. The text that is there in the pdf/photo is in Hindi language. Could you suggest how could I achieve slice those articles from a pdf/photo? I mean to ask technology I will need to understand or libraries if any I will have to use. Any resources will be helpful. Thanks for the reply again.

Comment: Sadly, all that work was for a former employer. The good news is that the PDF spec is public, so you can write a parser. The bad news is that the spec is huge. PDF is written in Postscript so any Postcript parser should work, but I think unless you find an open source package you'll have your work cut out for you.

Comment: See http://podofo.sourceforge.net/, I don't know anything about it, it was the first google hit on my search.

Comment: I use https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader to do automated testing against PDFs I generate. It is not a command line tool, but rather a (ruby) library.